# Android usb and PC communication

Tags: android, linux, usb

How to achieve the communication of Android usb with Linux code. I use the libusb library, and reference the code inside. But it can not communicate. pc code and mobile phone code any one is ok. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to move some files between your android device and the PC. An easier way to achieve is by using the adb interface to do that. You could create a batch file or shell script to execute the actions you want to perform on the android device.

Comment: I don't want to use the adb. I want to follow adb write a communication tool, such as the adb. but I modeled, it still can not communicate.